# Выбор уникальных элементов последовательности через две связи

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

В модели есть 3 сущности со связями многие-к-многим:

```
ItemType{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string TypeName {get;set}
  public ICollection<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

Item {
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string ItemName {get;set;}
  public ICollection<ItemType> Types {gey;set;}
  public ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}

User{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Item> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Как имея `List<ItemType> SelectedTypes` выбрать уникальных пользователей из этого списка? И как это правильно называется?

Comment: А в чем уникальность заключается? Одинаковый ID?

Comment: Нет, не одинаковый, а разный, т.е. нужно выбрать всех пользователей, которые пользовались выбранными типами инструмента. Естественно ID у этих пользователей будут разными.

Comment: `SelectedTypes.SelectMany(it => it.Items).SelectMany(i => i.Users).Distinct()` - так пробовали?

Comment: Работает так как я написал?

Comment: Не получается второй раз SelectMany написать. Ругается подчёркиванием.

Comment: Что именно подчеркивает и какое сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Как только пишу второй SelectMany, (писать приходится руками, т.к. подсказка перестаёт работать на втором), подчёркивается красным первый, с сообщением: Аргументы типа для метода ... не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа.
Я присваиваю результат в переменную List<User> Users, и пытался перед SelectedTypes указывать тип: List<User>, но без результатов.

Comment: А какую версию VS используете?

Comment: Создайте новый пустой консольный проект и попробуйте скомпилируется ли у вас вот такой код: https://pastebin.com/MtUnH2Ub

Comment: 2017
Да, такой код компилится и ошибок нет.  Сейчас попробую найти, где что не так.